# How to extend weeks in an input file from a lookup file?

Tags: file, awk, lookup, extend

How to use `awk command` to achieve this? Basically, I would like to `extend the weeks` from my input by `two weeks`. Thank you.

input:

```
week46_2015
week47_2015
week51_2015
week52_2015
```

lookup (this is the exact order):

```
week45_2015
week46_2015
week47_2015
week48_2015
week49_2015
week50_2015
week51_2015
week52_2015
week1_2016
week2_2016
week3_2016
week4_2016
week5_2016
```

output:

```
week46_2015
week47_2015
week48_2015,extended
week49_2015,extended
week51_2015
week52_2015
week1_2016,extended
week2_2016,extended
```

Answer (score 0):

this one-liner works for the given example:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;b[$0]=NR;next}
     7;FNR%2==0{for(i=b[$0]+1;i<=b[$0]+2;i++)print a[i]",extended"}' lookup input
```

- it checks ("extends" from) the every 2nd line in `input`, and insert the corresponding lines from `lookup` in order.
- `lookup` should not contain duplicated lines.